# EFS/Lovells/OME suspension for NSGV

Tags: suspension, suzuki, grand-vitara

I want to upgrade suspension at my Suzuki Grand Vitara 2013.
Currently I determined three variants:

1. EFS Elite full kit ([specs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Al2ihzc4XzqaMG4Yup32PLXwTlgZ4tnQ))
2. EFS shocks (from kit) + Lovells coils (Medium SFS32 + Medium SRR33)
3. OME Nitrocharger full kit ([specs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KI_HOqbM2vhG9nEkmFBWvVQPi1LUUn5w))

I want to lift my car, but don't want to loose in control on-road.

Maybe you have an experience with this car and kits. I would be happy to hear any review.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the ride height, then you change the handling characteristics...

You have to decide what you want and accept the consequences of the change.

For example people lower suspension for looks and handling, but suffer a harsher ride...

Without exact detail of shock settings and spring rates etc a general answer is all I can offer and I don't have that vehicle to test on.

I have made changes to vehicles in the past, such as increasing roll stiffness - by fitting two anti-roll bars in place of 1... worked brilliantly....

Comment: I understand this, center of gravity will be raised. But a consultant said that EFS shocks are too soft and body roll will increase. On the other hand on forums I found a lot of info, that EFS suspension is stiff. So I'm confused

Comment: Perhaps the consultant assumed efs shocks with standard springs, perhaps you did not explain exactly what you are planning, perhaps the consultant assumed you would be fitting the complete kit....